What is the true meaning of release-acquire in C++?
This Q&A aims to thoroughly understand the intricacies of using release-acquire memory order for atomic operations in C++.
First, I'll provide my understanding of the release-acquire semantics, then I'll present my doubts about a specific case in C++ concurrent programming, and finally, I'll propose a more appropriate case to illustrate the concept.

My understanding of release-acquire semantics (see https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order)

memory_order_release:

No reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered after this store.

This essentially provides load->store and store->store ordering guarantees within the current thread.


All writes in the current thread are visible in other threads that acquire the same atomic variable.

The semantics imply that the write to the atomic variable in the current thread is visible to all threads that acquire the same atomic variable simultaneously (not individually). Once a release operation enters the coherence system, it effectively enters a global order, making it visible to all threads, not just some.



memory_order_acquire:

No reads or writes in the current thread can be reordered before this load.

This essentially provides load->load and load->store ordering guarantees within the current thread.


All writes in other threads that release the same atomic variable are visible in the current thread.

Any release to the atomic variable by other threads will be observed by the current thread's acquire operation (similarly, not just to some acquire operations).



The above is my understanding of the release-acquire semantics.

My doubts about a demo explaining release-acquire in C++ concurrent programming (this case seems to be adapted from the sequential consistency demo on cppreference)


Here is a demo from a book explaining release-acquire. The book claims that the final assert will trigger, but after testing on x86 and ARM, I found it never triggers. My doubts about this case are not just because I couldn't reproduce the result, but also based on the theoretical foundation I presented above. The reasons are:

A store operation corresponding to a release is visible to all acquire threads, not just some. Based on this understanding, there must be a global (write) order for X and Y when applied to memory, ensuring that threads c and d see the same result; either x->y or y->x, but never c sees x->y while d sees y->x.

The second piece of evidence is that release-acquire guarantees:

Store->Store

Load->Store

Load->Load

But misses Store->Load
Therefore, if the code in each thread does not involve Store->Load patterns, we can ensure a global order when applied to memory.





Based on the above understanding, I think the following example is more reasonable for explaining release-acquire. Here, release-acquire model is used to operate atomic variables, and Store->Load semantics are constructed within each thread. Since release-acquire does not guarantee Store->Load order, it is highly likely that both threads will fail to complete the c++, ultimately causing the assert to fail.


The True Semantics of Release-Acquire

Have you gone and read the description of the C++ memory model from the actual standard?  It's not written in terms of "reordering" at all.  The cppreference treatment is an attempt to describe the model in a different way, which they think is more accessible but in the past they have introduced mistakes.

Please do not post code as an image; it makes it impossible to copy/paste for commentary or testing, and some people who use screen readers etc can't read it at all.

Your excerpt from the book is talking about IRIW reordering.  There are very few hardware architectures that can do it, and neither x86 nor ARM can.  POWER is the most commonly cited example.  But the C++ memory model does allow it.

And indeed this goes to show that you can't define the memory model solely in terms of StoreLoad, LoadStore, etc, because those only treat the ordering of two operations occuring in the same thread.

Your code example in #3 certainly demonstrates one type of reordering behavior that release/acquire allows.  But you seem to be proposing that it is a complete description of that behavior; yet the IRIW example shows that it is not.

Thank you for your answer@Nate Eldredge. I also had doubts about the problem of logical cores (or hyperthreading) mentioned in the paper you cited, and the problem of some platform data not being globally visible after entering the cache system. But from the c++ documentation, I feel that c++ release-acquire may essentially have a nice vision of stores preserving global order, but compromising to accommodate certain hardware architectures.

"The True Semantics of Release-Acquire" this seems to be an artifact of the question-writing-wizard. Please forget the wizard and reread your question. Please include code as text. And please make sure there is an actual specific focused question. Currently there isnt any


This essentially provides load->store and store->store ordering guarantees within the current thread.

... but only for the release store. In other words, loads and stores cannot move from before the release store to after the release store.

The semantics imply that the write to the atomic variable in the current thread is visible to all threads that acquire the same atomic variable simultaneously (not individually).

This is faulty logic. If a thread acquire-loads the same atomic object in thread T2 and sees the value that was release-stored in T1, then all stores that occurred in T1 before the release-store are visible in T2. This does not imply anything about the simultaneity of the effect across multiple loading threads. In fact, C++ places no such restriction. What C++ provides is that once the store is visible in a loading thread, what occurred in the storing thread becomes visible.

Once a release operation enters the coherence system, it effectively enters a global order, making it visible to all threads, not just some.

In the C++ memory model, there is no coherence system. On particular implementations on particular platforms, stronger guarantees may be available. Technically, both are required. A C++ implementation may violate a stronger guarantee even if it is true at the processor level. However, in some cases, in order to provide the guarantee that C++ requires, on a platform with stronger guarantees, the natural implementation choices will bring those along.
Likewise, there is no global order here. There is a global order for sequentially consistent operations and that also holds across atomic objects.
I want to emphasize that the C++ memory model lives above the processor. It controls what transformations the compiler can perform as well. And two good, compliant implementations may choose different transformations.
Similar comments apply on the acquire side.

The book claims that the final assert will trigger, but after testing on x86 and ARM

It asserts that it can trigger, and it can. The guarantees are:

Any stores before the store to x in write_x are visible after the loop in read_x_then_y (there are none)
Any stores before the store to y in write_y are visible after the loop in read_y_then_x (there are none)

There is no other guarantee from the release-acquire synchronization. read_x_then_y can observe x true and y false, and read_y_then_x can observe y true and x false.
The first piece of evidence is built on a faulty assumption, as noted above. The second piece of evidence is faulty as well. Recall that the ordering requirements are about load and acquire of the same atomic variable, not general store-load, etc. reorderings.
Finally, x86 is has a strong processor memory model. ARM is in the middle. The C++ memory model is weaker than both, to permit platforms weaker than both.

(comment) but compromising to accommodate certain hardware architectures

It really isn't. Release-acquire synchronization is both compatible with weaker architectures and also one of the most important guarantees that is needed in practice.

I think the following example is more reasonable for explaining release-acquire

The guarantees are similar here, so it's also a solid example, but doesn't look that different to me.
